# How to globally handle exceptions in ASP.NET WebApi when exception is raised through JsonNetFormatter

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, error-handling, asp.net-web-api2

We develop *ASP.NET MVC5* app with *WebApi2* and *AngularJs*. For serialization and deserialization we use custum JsonNetFormatter as follow:

```
public class JsonNetFormatter : MediaTypeFormatter
{

    //  other codes for formatting

    public override Task WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext)
    {
        string NameOfSet = "";
        ObjectWrapperWithNameOfSet obj = value as ObjectWrapperWithNameOfSet;
        if (obj != null)
        {
            NameOfSet = obj.NameOfSet;
            value = obj.WrappedObject;
        }

        _jsonSerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CustomContractResolver(NameOfSet);

        // Create a serializer
        JsonSerializer serializer = JsonSerializer.Create(_jsonSerializerSettings);

        // Create task writing the serialized content
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            using (JsonTextWriter jsonTextWriter = new JsonTextWriter(new StreamWriter(writeStream, SupportedEncodings[0])) { CloseOutput = false })
            {
                serializer.Serialize(jsonTextWriter, value);
                jsonTextWriter.Flush();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and WebApiConfig as follow:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes

        config.Formatters.Clear();
        config.Formatters.Insert(0, new JsonNetFormatter());
    }
}
```

The application work fine. but in some situation we get an errors when deserialization json data. My question is How can we handle these errors and send to the client side?

Example for the errors:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own custom exception handler to modify any error messages before sending it to client

```
    public class ErrorHandler : ExceptionHandler
    {
        public override void Handle(ExceptionHandlerContext context)
        {

            context.Result = new TextPlainErrorResult()
            {
                Request = context.ExceptionContext.Request,
                Content = "Oops! Sorry! Something went wrong." + "Please contact support so we can try to fix it."
            };
        }

        private class TextPlainErrorResult : IHttpActionResult
        {
            public HttpRequestMessage Request { get; set; }

            public string Content { get; set; }

            public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, Content);
                return Task.FromResult(response);
            }
        }
    }
```

and then register this custom class in config class like following

`config.Services.Replace(typeof(IExceptionHandler), new ErrorHandler());`